# LZMA Based Archiving on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, compression, tar

I am trying to build an archiving system. I have tested out LZMA compression algorithm, and it provides very good results. However, I need the ability to add and retrieve(will remain in the archive) files.

Is there any way of doing that? 
I tried creating a tarball, and compressing it with xz tools(lzma command). but I don't see any way that I could add or retrieve individual files without decompressing/re-compressing the whole file.

Compressing individual files is not really appropriate in my case, since the files have a lot of duplicated data between them.

Thanks

Comment: I have been using 7za for now. But still open to better suggestions.

Comment: You need to compress individual files if you want to extract only one of them without decompressing the whole file.